# Measure total amount of RAM available to application

Tags: c#, memory-management

I have a data parsing application I have been working on and given the sheer size of the text files it is reading, controlling memory usage is key for good performance. The two part strategy here first measures how much RAM each file would contribute to the sum total, but it also needs to know how much RAM is available to the application at a given point in time. If enough RAM is available, the application opts to do its processing in memory. Otherwise, it switches to a mode that performs all or most of the operations on disk.

Measuring a file's contribution to memory usage is quick and easy:

```
    static Int64 GetSizeInMemory(string path)
    {
        //THIS CODE IS SPEEDY
        Int64 r = ((Func<Int64>)(
                    () =>
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                using (Stream s = new MemoryStream())
                                {
                                    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                                    formatter.Serialize(s, File.ReadAllLines(path));
                                    return s.Length;
                                }
                            }
                            catch
                            {
                                //this file is way too big
                                return -1;
                            }
                        }
                ))();
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        return r;
    }
```

However, measuring the total amount of memory available is slow and difficult. In this case, I attempted to do so by trapping the stack overflow error, which in my thinking should give the most reliable figure.

```
    static Int64 GetMaxAllowedMemory()
    {
        //THIS CODE IS SLOW
        Int64 r = ((Func<Int64>)(
                    () =>
                        {
                            byte[] b = new byte[]{};
                            Int64 rs = 0;
                            while (true)
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    Array.Resize<byte>(ref b, b.Length + 1);
                                    b[b.Length - 1] = new byte();
                                    rs = b.Length;
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            b = null;
                            return rs;
                        }
                ))();
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        return r;
    }
```

Is there a better approach I should be using here?

**Please note** I have looked at a number of questions similar to this one on Stack Overflow, but most deal only with obtaining a figure for the total amount of available RAM on the computer, which is not the same as the maximum amount of RAM a .NET process is allowed at runtime.

**UPDATE**

After receiving an answer, I came up with the following that allows me to get the total amount of RAM available to the application.

```
    static Int64 GetMemoryFailPoint()
    {
        Int64 r = ((Func<Int64>)(
                    () =>
                    {
                        int rs = 1;
                        while (true)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                using (new System.Runtime.MemoryFailPoint(rs))
                                {
                                }
                            }
                            catch {
                                break;
                            }
                            rs++;
                        }
                        return Convert.ToInt64(rs) * 1000000;
                    }
                ))();
        return r;
    }
```

Comment: For your update, you likely can make your code a lot faster by going up by doubling the value till it fails then divide by 2 and walk up slowly after that point. Also, per [the remarks section of the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.memoryfailpoint(v=vs.110).aspx) *"MemoryFailPoint operates at a granularity of 16 MB. Any values smaller than 16 MB are treated as 16 MB, and other values are treated as the next largest multiple of 16 MB"*  so `rs++` should be `rs += 16`, you are doing 15 extra checks that will return the same result.

Comment: Lastly, There are `1 << 20` (`1048576`) bytes in a MB, so your return should be `return Convert.ToInt64(rs) * (1 << 20);`. For 2048 MB (2GB) that would be a difference of 99,483,648 Bytes.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thanks! I will definitely consider that. Also, the pointer about the return is most helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use the [`MemoryFailPoint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.memoryfailpoint(v=vs.110).aspx) class:

```
try
{
    using (new System.Runtime.MemoryFailPoint(1024)) // 1024 megabytes
    {
        // Do processing in memory
    }
}
catch (InsufficientMemoryException)
{
    // Do processing on disk
}
```

---

*Based on this [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28100651/2878550).*

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reading the entire file in to memory and seeing if it fails or not you can insead use [`MemoryFailPoint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.memoryfailpoint(v=vs.110).aspx) to check to see if there is enough ram available to do the in-memory processing by using the size of the file on the disk.

```
void ProcessFile(string path)
{
    try
    {
        var fileInfo = new FileInfo(path);
        var fileSizeInMb = (int)(fileInfo.Length >> 20);
        using (new System.Runtime.MemoryFailPoint(fileSizeInMb))
        {
            // Do processing in memory
        }
    }
    catch (InsufficientMemoryException)
    {
        // Do processing on disk
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not appear to be an accurate measure of the impact of a file. When I run my original function to test the size in memory of the file, I get 166.6 MB in size, and using file info I get ~159 MB. That's 7.7 MB less impact. It would apples and oranges to compare file size to the measured impact on RAM from reading it into memory.

Comment: Never mind. MemoryFailPoint does in fact allow one to determine the total amount of memory available before a stack overflow error occurs. However, it is not proper to measure it by file size because the size in memory is greater than the size on disk.

Comment: @JoshuaDannemann MemoryFailpoint has a resolution of 16 MB anyway, it rounds up to the next 16MB chunk (see the documentation), so a 7 MB difference likely would not make a huge difference.

Comment: Rounding up or not, the point is that the files themselves have a greater size in memory than on disk. So the number returned by fileinfo is markedly lower than what the size in memory really is. 7 MB difference, given the slim margins of my program's memory requirements is quite significant. However, I can use MemoryFailPoint to get the total amount of available memory by running it in a loop.